# python using pyomo ValueError: More than one active objective defined for input model 'unknown'; Cannot write legal LP file

Tags: python, pyomo

My objective is to create a hydropower generation model and identify the optimal water level dispatching process. However, I'm encountering errors when attempting to call the Gurobi solver using Pyomo. Although I have recently learned Pyomo, I have made several attempts to resolve the errors without success. Although there are no grammatical errors in my code, I'm still quite confused by the issue：

```
ValueError: More than one active objective defined for input model 'unknown'; Cannot write legal LP file
Objectives: obj[1] obj[2]
```

I think there may be an issue with this section of the code：

```
def object_rule(model, a):
    return K * model.Q[a] * (model.H[a] + model.H[a + 1]) / 2 * 8760 * 3600 / 1000
#K is the coefficient, Q is the flow rate, H is the head, and a represents the time period
```

and

```
model.obj = Objective(model.T, rule=object_rule, sense=maximize)
```

This is my second time editing this question. I have taken into account the suggestions offered by many experts and have come to the realization that I still need to learn and make improvements.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code. You need to put the code in a code block (use the `{}` button, or three backticks on a line to mark beginning and end).

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the error message `More than one active objective defined` because you have an indexed objective function. Most solvers can only handle a single objective function at a time. I'm guessing the fix in your case is to sum over `model.T` in your `object_rule` rule something like:

```
def object_rule(model): 
    return sum(K * model.Q[a] * (model.H[a] + model.H[a + 1]) / 2 * 8760 * 3600 / 1000 for a in model.T)
model.obj = Objective(rule=object_rule, sense=maximize)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The question has been answered.